# How can I apply color adjustments for vector CYMK output?

Tags: vector

I sometimes rasterize vector designs (at a very very high DPI, so no effect is had on the clarity, but file size suffers) in order to take them into Photoshop and apply a myriad of composite color adjustments such as *color balance*, *curve*, *levels*, *hue*, etc.

I was told (in a comment on this site) that this can be done without rasterizing my design, but I haven't seen any way to apply such alterations in InDesign, which is where I do most of my vector design. I have InDesign and Illustrator available - **How does one apply color alterations to vector with one of these tools?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to have these tools atleast in illustrator.

- Color balance can be found in illustrator under **Edit → Edit Color → Color balance**, from the same menu you can also desaturate the image etc...
- Astute graphics has a plugin suite called [phantasm](http://astutegraphics.com/software/phantasm/) that has all the rest of this functionality.

There's really no reason why shuch tools couldn't exist in InDesign.